# sorting rows in a csv files using Pandas column wise with specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a quick question regarding sorting rows in a csv file using Pandas. The CSV file which I have has the data that looks like:

```
item,description,Qty,Price
BILL NO : 1121,,,
xxx,aaa,1,232
yyy,bbb,1,382
aaa,ccc,1,46
ccc,ddd,1,50
,,Total,856
```

I need to sort in the following way: sort the 1st column item on alphabet-wise. So the output should look like the following:

```
item,description,Qty,Price
BILL NO : 1121,,,
aaa,ccc,1,46
ccc,ddd,1,50
xxx,aaa,1,232
yyy,bbb,1,382
,,Total,856
```

Any help/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: .sort_values helps but the blank line comes to the top like the below item,description,Qty,Price
,,Total,856 BILL NO : 1121,,,
aaa,ccc,1,46
ccc,ddd,1,50
xxx,aaa,1,232
yyy,bbb,1,382

Comment: So the blank is actually not an `NaN` but `''`?